# Javassist: access method parameters in a replace call

Tags: java, javassist

I am substituting a statement inside a method call and I was wondering if it was possible to access its method parameters from within a `replace` call. I read through the Javassist guide but could not find any info about it.

Note that I can achieve this by replacing the method body, but I prefer a simpler solution if possible. 
An example is given below:

```
void doSomething(boolean isValid) {
   // many lines of code...
   executeSomething(isValid ? withThis : orThat);
}
```

```
...
CtMethod cm = ctClass.getDeclaredMethod("doSomething");
cm.instrument(new ExprEditor() {
   @Override
   public void edit(MethodCall m) throws CannotCompileException {
      if ("executeSomething".equals(m.getMethodName())) {
         m.replace("{ $1 = booleanIsValid ? 1 : 2; $_ = $proceed($$); }");
      }
   }
});
```

As you can see I want to retrieve the value of the parameter `isValid` in the substitution.
I was hoping `$args` inside the `replace` call would contain the method parameter, but it doesn't.

Any advice on how to achieve this?

Comment: Not really clear what's your goal. Can you further elaborate what do you mean with 'retrive'?